# back-end and front-end options in RoR3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am starting learning Ruby on Rails, and as far as i am understanding, there are two ways about how to aproach programming in RoR and designing the web application:

1. Designing the back-end in RoR (data model, engine, etc), offering API in JSON (it could be done by team A). By this way, you can build up the front-end in HTML5+CSS3+JavaScript separately, and communicating with the back-end through JSON (done by team B).
2. Building up the web application entirely on RoR, the back-end and front-end integrated.

As far as i understand with this two ways, the first option is advisable when you are programming not only for web application, but for other plataforms, like mobiles or tablets (iphone, ipads, etc), because you are offering a REST API to communicate with different platforms. But the second option is ideal if you want to get the power of productivity of RoR, because you dont have to design API.

What are my options if I want to design a web app with mobile features capabilities for the future?

I am interested in your experiences with this decision.  Please back your answers up with facts.

Comment: There's no silver bullet, you know :-)

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev, but it could be awesome :-)

Answer (score 0):

I feel that Rails companies are now looking for people who are familiar with the full stack(front and back end), --you will always have people who are stronger in one area or another of course--

For personal experience I can say that I've seen better results when front and back end are integrated, people are exposed to both sides and are able to sort out issues while the project is in development and to be honest I can't think of any reason why following this method would affect future mobile development.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But one question. Even if both ends (back and front) are integrated, do they still communicate through REST JSON? if its like this, it could be used as API for mobile platforms, right?